# C++ C2059 error when trying to define variable at compile time

Tags: c++

I have a variable VER that I am trying to define at compile time with the -DVER= using g++ and /DVER= with MS VS 2010 Express.  It works in g++ but doesn't compile with MS VS.  I found an example on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf.aspx referencing empty symbols.  I think this is not applicable because if the /D switch is not used I have a default in the foo.h file.

Here is an example of what I have

foo.h

```
#ifndef VER
#define VER = 1.0
#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
void write_ver(std::ofstream &output)
{  
float ver = VER; // C2059 Error here (Error: expected an expression)
output << ver << std::endl;
}
```

The output is error C2059: syntax error : '='.

If there is a better way to accomplish what I am doing I am open to suggestions as well.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: `#define` syntax does not use an equal sign. Your preprocessor substitutes `float ver = = 1.0;` at the line of the error. Just use `#define VER 1.0`, and you are fine.

Comment: Thanks, now my stupidity gets recorded for all time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define VER = 1.0
```

remove the assignment operator from the above line and you should be fine. Preprocesser definitions have the form:

```
#define NAME VALUE
```